# What is the new retrievedEntities in breeze.QueryResult?

Tags: breeze

I have notice a new property - retrievedEntities on the breeze.QueryResult object.

Googling only turned up this -

https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/commit/7eb5deda8dfcff83ddf5a2cecf39ae21a9266a9b

Which is a check-in with comment

> "Added retrievedEntities property to results object returned by
>   entity…"

On another note - how do I view the full entire check-in comment on github?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `retrievedEntities` property is an array of all the entities that were returned by the query.  This will differ from the `results` property when your query uses `.expand()` to get related entities.  For example, the object returned by the query

```
var query = EntityQuery.from('Orders')
.take(20)
.expand('Customer, OrderDetails');
```

would have a `results` property that is an array of 20 `Order` entities; each `Order` would have its associated `Customer` and `OrderDetail` entities attached to it in a graph.

The `retrievedEntities` property would  be a flat array of all `Order`, `Customer`, and `OrderDetail` entities.  This may or may not be useful, depending on what you are doing with the query results.

Thanks for the reminder to update the documentation!

P.S. The full comment is there in the [github commit](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/commit/7eb5deda8dfcff83ddf5a2cecf39ae21a9266a9b), but the second line is in a very small font (and very brief).